# PHP strtotime weird behaviour

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

This code was working fine until yesterday:

```
$fechaactual = strtotime('now');

$timestamp = strtotime($v->startDate);

$pelo = date("d/m G:i:s",$fechaactual);
$pelo2 = date("m/d G:i:s",$timestamp);

$timestamp = strtotime($pelo2);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($pelo);
```

Now, $timestamp2 is always empty. I do not understand. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use `strtotime()` multiple times.

The issue can be reproduced with the code below:

```
$fechaactual = strtotime('now');
$pelo = date("d/m G:i:s",$fechaactual);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($pelo);
var_dump($timestamp2);
```

Outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

`$fechaactual` will contain the timestamp for the current time, and by using `date()`, you're converting the timestamp into a readable format. Later, you're trying to use `strtotime()` on the new date string, but `strtotime()` fails to understand that format and returns `FALSE`.

`strtotime()` understands the formats listed in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

If you want to parse a date string with a custom format, it's better to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

Comment: The error is more subtle than that. `strtotime()` would return a timestamp until 12th October as it saw `12/10`, and interpreted that as 10th December. On 13th October strtotime saw `13/10` which it can no longer interpret (month 13 is invalid), and returned `false`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% about this but the fact it worked till yesterday may mean its formatting issue.

Today is 13/10/2013 in UK format.
In US that would equate to the 10th day of the 13th month which isn't a valid date... Yesterday would have equated to 10th day of 12th month which would be a valid date although not the date you were expecting.